# How Do I Transfer Grid view values to next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How Do I Transfer Grid view values to next page. Grid view consist one of the text box(`txtItemGroup`) which values have to be entered by the user dynamically, not from the Data base.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TestItemName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Items Group">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TestItemGroup") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemGroup" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Values">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblItemValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TestItemValues") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default Values">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDefaultValues" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DefaultValues") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your GridView's RowCommand event put in the following code:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Send")
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)GridView1.FindControls("txtItemGroup");
    Session["ItemGroup"] = txt.Text;    
}
```

In addition to this, put a Button or LinkButton in your GridView's ItemTemplate to send the value of the appropriate Textbox as you have put a TextBox and set it's CommandName property in the .aspx page as:

```
<asp:Button id="btnSend" runat="server" Text = ">" commandName="Send"/>
```

And then in the Page_Load event of the page where you want the value of TextBox to be viewed:

```
if (!IsPostback)
{
    Label1.Text = Session["ItemGroup"].ToString();
    //or
    Label1.Text = (String)Session["ItemGroup"];
}
```

Comment: @ Shah Abdul Latif: Thank you.. It is giving the following Error.The name 'txtItemGroup' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It showing Like this: GridView' does not contain a definition for 'FindControls' and no extension method 'FindControls' 
accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Give the name of your GridView
e.g. if the name of gridView is GridView1 then write as:

    TextBox txt = (TextBox)GridView1.FindControls("txtItemGroup");

and in the FindControl method give the name of the Textbox, which you have put in the item template of the gridView, as string.

Comment: @ Shah Abdul Latif: Thank you. Ya i got it. but every row of Textbox in gridview i need to click the button which is placed on gridview.. but is there any other solution to do the same thing in outside the gridview i.e button click. in (protected void btnSend1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e))

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

Add a button just below that textbox like this:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsend" Text="Send" runat="server" CommandName="Send" />
```

In RowCommand event write like this:-

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Send")
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
            TextBox TextBox1 = row.FindControl("txtItemGroup") as TextBox;
            Response.Redirect("yourasppage.aspx?txt=" + TextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

On page load of `yourasppage.aspx' use this code

`string txtval = Request.QueryString["txt"];`

Hope this will help

Comment: @ sharique ansari: Thank you.. By using RowCommand there is no problem. I just need to the same in button click which is placed in  outside the Grid view.

Comment: @Nani you need to find that row in which that text box is, so u can use GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl

Comment: @Nani so my recommend is create a rowcommand for that text box on change and get the row index you can store it in a session and use that index on button click

Comment: To get all the row you can use a for loop, for(int i=0;i<GridView1.Rows.Count:i++){TextBox txt=GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtItemGroup") as TextBox;}